# RF Transmitter and Receivers for Raspberry Pi

Tags: wireless, video, data-transfer

Which type of RF transmitter and receivers can be used to transmit video over the range of more than 500m. ?

Comment: I can't see the relevance to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Raspberry Pi will be used for the optimization of video (for encoding and decoding and for encryption).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [wifibroadcast](https://befinitiv.wordpress.com/wifibroadcast-analog-like-transmission-of-live-video-data/) which uses off-the-shelf WiFi hardware :

> **Why normal wifi is a bad choice for FPV applications**
>
> - Association: Video transmitter and receiver need to be associated. If one device looses association (for example due to too weak signal strength) the video transmission stops instantly.
> - Error-free transmission: Wifi transmits either data that is correct or no data.
> - Two-way communication: Even if you are sending data only from source to sink a bi-directional data flow is required using wifi. The reason for this is that a wifi receiver needs to acknowledge the received packets.
> - One to one transfers: Unless you use broadcast frames or similar techniques a normal wifi data flow is a one to one connection.
>
> **What wifibroadcast makes different**
>
> Wifibroadcast puts the wifi cards into monitor mode. This mode allows to send and receive arbitrary packets without association.
>
> Additionally, it is also possible to receive erroneous frames (where the checksum does not match). This way a true unidirectional connection is established **which mimics the advantageous properties of an analog link**.
>
> Wifibroadcast uses Forward Error Correction to archive a high reliability at low bandwidth requirements. It is able to repair lost or corrupted packets at the receiver.

Comment: Wifi is a good option .. But
Its our FYP requirement to work on radio channel ..

Comment: Wifi works on a [radio channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_wave), usually a fairly high (2-5 Ghz) frequency one.